# Maven Shade plugin , main class not found (Scala, Intellij)

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, maven-shade-plugin

I tried to look around a lot to solve this problem but I can't really solve it.
In my `scala` project i'm trying to build a `fatjar` with all the dependencies in it, so here is my pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>com.my.project.start.CommandStarter</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions> 
</plugin>
```

So i'm pointing to my main class, and in the `manifest` , inside the `jar` , i can see that the main class is there too..

But when i run my jar by launching : `scala myjar.jar` i have a

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Any suggestion?

Thank you!